# Segmentation fault with allocation of pointer array?

Tags: c++, function, pointers, struct, segmentation-fault

I have spent the past few hours trying to figure out why I am getting a seg-fault. My code runs fine, being that my nameList pointer array is initialized with the names that I enter. However, when I pass nameList to my function to dynamically allocate the right amount of space per name in the createStudentList function. If you have any ideas, please inform me with an explanation, I am not looking only for an answer to fix it. Thank you. (This is an assignment, so some guidelines need to be followed [such as using char arrays instead of strings].)

Here is my code:

```
#include "main.h"
using namespace std;

const int MAXCHAR = 101;

struct Student
{
    char *name;
    double gpa;
};

Student ** createStudentList(char ** names, int size);

int main()
{
    int size = 0;
    char temp[MAXCHAR];
    char **nameList = nullptr;
    Student **studentList = nullptr;

    cout << "Enter amount of names: ";
    cin >> size;
    cout << endl;
    cin.clear();
    cin.ignore(10, '\n');
    nameList = new char *[size];

    for(auto i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {   
        cout << "Enter name: ";
        cin.get(temp, MAXCHAR, '\n');
        cout << endl;
        cin.ignore(10, '\n');
        nameList[i] = new char[strlen(temp) + 1]; 
        strcpy(nameList[i], temp);
    }   

    studentList = createStudentList(nameList, size);

    return 0;
}

Student ** createStudentList(char ** names, int size)
{
    Student **tempStudentList = nullptr;
    tempStudentList = new Student *[size];


    for(auto idx = 0; idx < size; idx++)
    {
        tempStudentList[idx]->name = new char[strlen(names[idx]) + 1];
        strcpy(tempStudentList[idx]->name, names[idx]);
        tempStudentList[idx]->gpa = 0;
    }
    return tempStudentList;
}
```

Comment: This is not modern C++, use vector and strings from standard library. You should not rely on raw pointers.

Comment: Please show us a case that it cause a seg fault

Comment: @tomekpe I would, but I have to follow the guidelines of the assignment. I am taking a C++ class and it is required to do it this way. Sorry

Comment: @tomekpe: it is 100% true. However, it is an assignment and the OP has specific restriction

Comment: @HumamHelfawi Not sure what you mean, but this is what gdb tells me. I typed two names (Ryan and Ben) and then try to pass nameList to the function. 

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0000000000400e2c in createStudentList (names=0x614c20, size=2) at main.cpp:52
52   tempStudentList[idx]->name = new char[strlen(names[idx]) + 1];

Comment: @Ry23 no problem. my compiler did not catch the problem and behave as expected so I asked for special case. However,  Sean has catched it and answered your question well.

Comment: BTW, notice that you have a huge memory leak. You have to 'delete' all the objects that you have 'new'ed

Comment: @HumamHelfawi Thank you, after i finish the create function, I will then be adding a delete function

Comment: And if you can't use `string` and std containers for any reason, assignment requirements for example, familiarize yourself with the [Rule of Three/Five](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three). Save yourself much anguish it can.

Comment: Ya, it was definitely the assignment requirements, it's odd that we are unable to use string in this class. I assume that she just wants us to understand the baritone basics? I will definitely look into the Rule of Three/Five, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not allocating the `Student` instances in the loop. Try this:

```
for(auto idx = 0; idx < size; idx++)
{
    tempStudentList[idx] = new Student;

    tempStudentList[idx]->name = new char[strlen(names[idx]) + 1];
    strcpy(tempStudentList[idx]->name, names[idx]);
    tempStudentList[idx]->gpa = 0;
}
```

Also, as pointed out in the comments, this isn't modern C++. You'd be better off using `std::string` and `std::vector`. For example, change `Student` to be:

```
struct Student
{
    std::string name;
    double gpa;
};
```

add use `std::vector` in `createStudentList`:

```
std::vector<Student> createStudentList(const std::vector<string> &names)
{
    std::vector<Student> students;    

    for(auto idx = 0; idx < names.size(); idx++)
    {
        Student student;
        student.name = names[index];
        student.gpa = 0

        students.push_back(student);
    }

    return students;
}
```

This will save you having to allocate raw memory which you would otherwise need to delete.

Comment: I would reserve before pushing back. students.reserve(names.size());

Comment: `std::vector<Student> students(names.size());` would work as well.

Comment: Thank you @Sean! I will give that a try, can't believe I hadn't noticed that. Sometimes you stare for so long you miss the obvious.

Thank you for the tips on vector. I am in school right now and am rather disappointed that my teacher is teaching us C++ that is not modern any longer. I will really need to learn more once this semester is over. Thank you for the help though! Also, that is good to know that those will help with the deletion too. After this function is complete my other objective is to delete the allocated memory.

Answer (score 2):

The reason of segmentation fault:

```
for(auto idx = 0; idx < size; idx++)
{
    // tempStudentList[idx] is `Student *` and you don't allocate memory for it
    // this is UB
    tempStudentList[idx]->name = new char[strlen(names[idx]) + 1];
    strcpy(tempStudentList[idx]->name, names[idx]);
    tempStudentList[idx]->gpa = 0;
}
```

But, `tempStudentList` don't need to be `Student**` at all, `Student*` should be sufficient.

```
Student * createStudentList(char ** names, int size)
{
    Student *tempStudentList = new Student[size];
    for(auto idx = 0; idx < size; idx++)
    {
        tempStudentList[idx].name = new char[strlen(names[idx]) + 1];
        strcpy(tempStudentList[idx].name, names[idx]);
        tempStudentList[idx].gpa = 0;
    }
    return tempStudentList;
}
```

BTW: You need to `delete` many things, `nameList`, `nameList` 's elements, `studentList`, `name` of `Student`, and so on. That's why we should use STLs.

Comment: Thank you for the help @songyuanyao. It now works! As for the unnecessary **, I didn't have any other choice with the parameters I was given for this assignment.

As for the delete, I will be taking care of all of that in the next function I make which is a delete function. Thanks again!